# Ember app kit how can I exclude jquery from the list of included js libraries when I run grunt dist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, ember-app-kit

I'm using ember app kit to create an ember.js app. It's including jquery for me which works great when I'm running the as a standalone app using grunt server. However I would like to use grunt dist to compile it all down to a few single files for inclusion in another app. This other app already includes jquery so I would like to exclude jquery from being compiled/minified in with grunt dist. Short of deleting jquery from the vendor folder is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ember App Kit uses [bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) to install/remove the packages. Remove `$` from [bower.json](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/bower.json#L5)

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is managed by Bower in your case, you'd want to run
`bower uninstall jquery`

http://bower.io/#uninstalling-packages

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, I didn't actually need to use bower at all. While doing a

```
bower uninstall jquery
```

would indeed remove jquery from the vendor dir, and adding the bower.json would keep it from coming back, neither of these things would prevent it from getting added to my compiled, minified js that results from a

```
grunt dist
```

What I finally figured out is that the index.html has special comment blocks that dictate what grunt decides to include. Specifically the

```
<!-- build:js(tmp/result) /assets/vendor.min.js -->
```

dictates what gets included in the vendor.min.js output. In my case I simply removed jquery from this block. Another option would be to keep it in the block but include it in the

```
<!-- @if dist=false -->
```

block. Hope this helps anybody else with the same issue.